# WindowsIdentity Impersonation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, windows, windows-services

I have a web application to do bulk operations, e.g. emails, mail merge, etc... 
So I am planning to make a job pool table to define the jobs and create a windows service to process each job.
Now my problem is, when I process the job I have to impersonate as the person who define it to get the right permissions.

I found some un-managed code to impersonate with username, password and domain. But I can't use that as I don't keep the passwords in DB.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You cannot impersonate a user account without authentication. To do that you need the user name and password (or equivalent). If what you are trying to do were possible, it would immediately lose any notion of accountability.